# How to change a *.tbz's +INSTALL file, and repack the package in FreeBSD, without installing the package

Tags: package-management, freebsd, bsd-ports

I am running on FreeBSD 8.2, I have a device that will run NanoBSD 7.4. To install packages for nanobsd, you put them in `/usr/src/tools/tools/nanobsd/Pkg`, and uncomment the line in your config.

I need to get JamVM installed on the NanoBSD, this depends on `diablo-jre`. When `nanobsd.sh` tries to install the diablo package, the log `_.cust.cust_pkg` is spammed with `Do you accept the license [yes/no]`.

I need to unpack the diablo package and edit `+INSTALL`, then repack it. How can I do this?

Same question but on superuser: https://superuser.com/questions/290494/update-diablo-jre-freebsd7-i386-1-6-0-07-02-tbz-install-do-you-accept-when-ins

Comment: [Do not post the same questions to multiple sites.](http://unix.stackexchange.com/faq) Pick one, and delete the version on the other site (you may need to flag for a moderator to do it if you don't have enough reputation). In the future, if you want to move a question to a different site, flag for a moderator to migrate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unpack .tbz with `tar xf` to empty directory, edit `+INSTALL` and pack it again with `tar cjf ../new_package.tbz *`. FreeBSD's binary package is just bzipped tar archive, nothing special.

Comment: Hi, tried the command, but I get this error: tar xf diablo-jre-freebsd7.i386.1.6.0.07.02_12.tbz
diablo-jre1.6.0/man/ja/man1/: Cannot extract through symlink diablo-jre1.6.0/man/ja
diablo-jre1.6.0/man/ja/man1/unpack200.1: Cannot extract through symlink diablo-jre1.6.0/man/ja
diablo-jre1.6.0/man/ja/man1/tnameserv.1: Cannot extract through symlink diablo-jre1.6.0/man/ja
diablo-jre1.6.0/man/ja/man1/servertool.1: (snip)
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors.

Comment: did you extracted it to empty directory? I've tried `tar xf diablo-jre-1.6.0.07.02_13.tbz` on package created with `pkg_create -b` and it work just fine. Can you show full `tar` output?

Comment: Here you go http://pastebin.com/yyaaBni1

Comment: PS: [root@nano /usr/src/tools/tools/nanobsd/diablo]# md5 diablo-jre-freebsd7.i386.1.6.0.07.02_12.tbz
MD5 (diablo-jre-freebsd7.i386.1.6.0.07.02_12.tbz) = d6336d91c4731ef68f70f3ca063e34e9

Comment: I'm using this: http://www.freebsdfoundation.org/cgi-bin/download?download=diablo-jre-freebsd7.i386.1.6.0.07.02.tbz via http://www.freebsdfoundation.org/downloads/java.shtml - just to be more verbose...

Comment: I used --exclude "diablo-jre1.6.0/man/ja/*" argument when calling tar.